# Which is ilo, and which is milo?

Tags: ilomilo

Whenever I play [**ilomilo**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilomilo), I can't keep track of which character is **ilo** (*Ilona*), and which character is **milo** (*Milton*).  I really enjoy **ilomilo**, but I need to know which **-ilo** is which, because in **ilomilo** I'm constantly getting my **milo** confused with my **ilo**, and my **ilo** confused with my **milo**.  I feel that calling your **ilo**  **milo** and your **milo**  **ilo** kind of ruins the cheery atmosphere you feel when you play as **ilo** and **milo** in **ilomilo**.

---

[image: ilomilo]

---

*TL;DR:  Which character is 'ilo', and which one is 'milo'?*

Comment: the whole ilomilo thing made my head turn..

Comment: It says when you select _play multiplayer_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ilo is red, Milo is blue.  That's it! :)

<sub>Sources: [[1]](http://www.brighthub.com/video-games/console/articles/106758.aspx), [[2]](http://www.annathered.com/2011/01/31/bento-82-ilomilo/)</sub>

Comment: also, you could make a meme out of that like "rilo and mlue" to remember which is which.